# jQuery to DETECT the PARENT at unknown level above?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, parent-child, parent

How to detect the parent at unknown level above?

For example:

```
<div id="parent-a">
    <....>
        <....>
            <div class="the-child" /> <!-- Comment 1 -->
        </....>
    </....>
</div>
<div id="parent-b">
    <....>
        <div class="the-child" /> <!-- Comment 2 -->
    </....>
</div>
```

`<....>` DOMS may be any unknown elements (in any much numbers) in between.

Then if i look upward from `the-child` at `Comment 1`, how do i know its parent is `div#parent-a` ?

Same thing again, if i look upward from `the-child` at `Comment 2`, how do i know its parent is `div#parent-b` ?

Comment: `.parents("#dnowhereyougoing")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) for such tasks.
But you have to have at least some identifiers for the parent element you want to target, so, e.g., this would work:

```
// for version one
var parent = $( '.the_child' ).parents( '#parent-a' );

// for version two
var parent = $( '.the_child' ).parents( '#parent-b' );
```

In both cases the first element, which is an ancestor of `the_child` element and matches the given selector is returned (if it exists).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if($('.the-child:first').closest('#parent-a').length){
    //success
}
```

But you may have to limit the selector `$('.the-child')` to something like a clicked child or a specific child because `$('.the-child')` will select all elements with the class `the-child`

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `parents` http://api.jquery.com/parents/

```
if($('.the-child').parents('#parent-b').length>0){}
```